# A little bit of Thank You to the undervalued janitors of the site

Tags: discussion

So, with the recent changes on Rep, I got bumped over the few points I was missing to get access to moderator tools.

With that, came the possibility of seeing deleted stuff, and with that possibility, came curiosity.

After poking around the site for a bit, checking for what does the stuff that gets deleted looks like, I came to appreciate the work of the mods/high rep uses quite a bit more.

So, guys, gals, and everyone else - thanks a bunch for keeping the signal-to-noise ratio awesomely high.

You guys (and gals, and everyone else) rock.

Comment: Welcome to the Janitorial team. :)

Comment: SE gets a lot funnier after you get to 10k, doesn't it?